# Get URL from mysql database for jplayer

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jplayer

I need to get the url for the artists track from the mysql databse for it to be played through jplayer.  I achieved it with the normal html audio controls but cannot do it with jplayer as the audio source is entered in javascript.

Here's how i achieved it with the html player;

```
<?php 
include ("../database.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE artistname='$artistname'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){



?> 
<br><br>
<audio controls="controls" height="50px" width="100px">
  <source src=<?php echo  $row['trackurl'] ?> type="audio/mp3" />
<embed height="50px" width="100px" src="song.mp3" />
</audio>

<?php } <?
```

Heres the javascript for jplayer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "http://localhost/uploads/dde85d7907e516545ba0860ef1ac23f2.mp3"
      });
    },
    swfPath: "../jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
```

The url from the mysql databse needs to go where it says: 
mp3: "http://localhost/uploads/dde85d7907e516545ba0860ef1ac23f2.mp3"

Comment: @dynamic You'll need to provide more context with that comment, or it is really unhelpful to the OP.  [What is MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? Why should the OP use it? Why is it preferred to the old `mysql_*()` API? (I'm not asking you, I know the answer)

Comment: I know i need to use mysqli, just haven't got round to learning it yet but will upgrade soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to get the the value and pass it to the jPlayer

Comment: Can i have a bit more information on this? An example of it or a link to how to do it? I know nothing about AJAX

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript make a variable of track like

```
var mp3file='<?php echo $row['trackurl']; ?>';
```

and then

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: "mp2file"
  });
```

This will work if you fetching a single song. If you fetching data in array then you need AJAX

Comment: I need to fetch an array. I dont know anything about AJAX sou could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: First of all can you correct me why do you need jquery jplayer plugin if you can play songs with HTML audio element? You php code should only enough if you just want to play songs.

Comment: I don't want to use the HTML player as it doesn't look great. I need a custom player as it will go in several other places on the site.